Distance between lines when using different clefs
When I use different clefs in different Scores, the distance from the top and between two lines are different. Normaly that wouldn't be a problem, but when they are next to each other it looks terrible (See image).
Has anyone an idea how to make the distances equal?

From this code I couldn't remote anything without loosing the problem. The scores are one in f3/c4 (See picture).
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[a5paper,                        % Seitenränder 
    top=0.75cm,
    bottom=1cm,
    left=1cm,
    right=1cm,
    headsep=5pt,
    includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}   % Zeilenabstand

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro}
\begin{document}
\gregorioscore{mag2}
Quia respéxit humilitátem ancíllæ \textbf{su}æ:~* \\
ecce enim ex hoc beátam me dicent omnes genera\textit{ti}\textbf{ó}nes.\\
\hspace{5mm}    Quia fecit mihi magna qui \textbf{pot}ens est:~* \\
\hspace{5mm}    et sanctum no\textit{men} \textbf{e}jus.\\
Et misericórdia ejus a progénie in pro\textbf{gé}nies~* \\
timénti\textit{bus} \textbf{e}um.\\
\hspace{5mm}    Fecit poténtiam in bráchio \textbf{su}o:~* \\
\hspace{5mm}    dispérsit supérbos mente cor\textit{dis} \textbf{su}i.\\
Depósuit poténtes de \textbf{se}de,~* \\
et exaltá\textit{vit} \textbf{hú}miles.\\
\hspace{5mm}    Esuriéntes implévit \textbf{bo}nis:~* \\
\hspace{5mm}    et dívites dimísit \textit{in}\textbf{á}nes.\\
Suscépit Israël púerum \textbf{su}um,~* \\
recordátus misericórdi\textit{æ} \textbf{su}æ.\\
\hspace{5mm}    Sicut locútus est ad patres \textbf{nos}tros,~* \\
\hspace{5mm}    Abraham et sémini ejus \textit{in} \textbf{sǽ}cula.\\
Glória Patri, et \textbf{Fí}lio,~* \\
et Spirítu\textit{i} \textbf{Sanc}to.\\
\hspace{5mm}    Sicut erat in princípio, et nunc, et \textbf{sem}per,~* \\
\hspace{5mm}    et in sǽcula sæculó\textit{rum}. \textbf{A}men.\\
\pagebreak
\gregorioscore{mag4}
Quia respéxit humilitátem an\textit{cíl}\textit{læ} \textbf{su}æ:~* \\
ecce enim ex hoc beátam me dicent omnes generati\textbf{ó}nes.\\
\hspace{5mm}    Quia fecit mihi ma\textit{gna} \textit{qui} \textbf{pot}ens est:~* \\
\hspace{5mm}    et sanctum nomen \textbf{e}jus.\\
Et misericórdia ejus a progénie \textit{in} \textit{pro}\textbf{gé}nies~* \\
timéntibus \textbf{e}um.\\
\hspace{5mm}    Fecit poténtiam in brá\textit{chi}\textit{o} \textbf{su}o:~* \\
\hspace{5mm}    dispérsit supérbos mente cordis \textbf{su}i.\\
Depósuit potén\textit{tes} \textit{de} \textbf{se}de,~* \\
et exaltávit \textbf{hú}miles.\\
\hspace{5mm}    Esuriéntes im\textit{plé}\textit{vit} \textbf{bo}nis:~* \\
\hspace{5mm}    et dívites dimísit in\textbf{á}nes.\\
Suscépit Israël pú\textit{e}\textit{rum} \textbf{su}um,~* \\
recordátus misericórdiæ \textbf{su}æ.\\
\hspace{5mm}    Sicut locútus est ad \textit{pa}\textit{tres} \textbf{nos}tros,~* \\
\hspace{5mm}    Abraham et sémini ejus in \textbf{sǽ}cula.\\
Glória Pa\textit{tri}, \textit{et} \textbf{Fí}lio,~* \\
et Spirítui \textbf{Sanc}to.\\
\hspace{5mm}    Sicut erat in princípio, et \textit{nunc}, \textit{et} \textbf{sem}per,~* \\
\hspace{5mm}    et in sǽcula sæculórum. \textbf{A}men.
\end{document}


Welcome! Does \grechangestaffsize{} help? See https://gregorio-project.github.io/gregoriotex/details.html (where the description isn’t perfectly clear to me).

Can you provide code for a minimal document demonstrating the issue?

@cfr a "minimal" example is rather difficult. I'll add a document to the post from which I couldn't remote anything without "loosing" the error.

Do the files mag2.gabc and mag4.gabc exist in a publicly accessible place (e.g., https://gregobase.selapa.net/)? The MWE can’t be compiled without them.

@Thérèse You can make them here: link, It's the 2. Tone and 4. Tone.

@ThomasKettel this is a good use of gabcsnippet in lieu of gregorioscore.
also, no, the issue is not solved by changing the staff size. The problem is complex; notice that it's as if the second score has notes above the staff, for which Gregorio (imperfectly) creates room; conversely LaTeX will either shrink or stretch scores to get as much as it thinks can/should fit on a page.

My preferred idea is to forego aligning the staves, and just "control the damage" by aligning the verses below (Quia respexit, etc.)
To do this you can use the facing-pages mode of paracol:
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{paracol}[1]*{2}
insert mag2 score here
\switchcolumn
insert mag4 score here
\switchcolumn* % this aligns the columns at this point
insert mag2 pointing here
\switchcolumn
insert mag4 pointing here
\end{paracol}

Or you can enclose each score in a fixed-height minipage, both minipage having the same height (the height of the "longest" score in terms of vertical length, that is, mag4 here).
